# Why can't I fix a spelling mistake that just adds two characters?

Tags: discussion, editing

I tried to make [this answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/should-i-monitor-my-childs-internet-usage/2753#2753) better by fixing the typo of "altertive" to "alternative", and was told that edits have to be a minimum of 6 characters.  Is this something that goes away if I had edit privileges?  (I haven't gained rep on parenting.se yet apart from the 100 bonus points from stackoverflow.)

Are spammy small edits such a serious problem that it's worth not accepting genuine typo fixes?  Just curious really (and a little miffed that my attempts to make the internet better have been refused).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the minimum character requirement goes away once you obtain full edit privileges.

Since edits from users without sufficient rep require manual approval, they are expected to be more substantial than simple typos.  We really do appreciate you taking the time to attempt to improve contributions, and **most** posts can benefit from more than one simple correction if you look hard enough, but for those few that really only need a couple of letters fixed you'll simply have to start posting some good questions and answers and get that rep :)